# Cookie doesn't get deleted with xml callback jquery php

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

I'm not sure if somebody asked this already, at least i cant find the answer so i'm wondering what i'm doing wrong with my script.

I'm trying to delete a cookie with a callback done by Jquery that calls a php script on the background, BUT, whatever i try i cannot get this to properly work (deleting the cookie).

I've checked the php website and even looked at the RFC 2109 memo to find out how browsers and php try to accomplish that the cookie will be deleted.

So, my question here is; How can this fail?

Edit: i don't get any error message, deleting the cookie manually works and creating the cookie with the same type of callback done by jquery does also work. It just doesn't get deleted when i try the same callback with jquery to run the PHP script in the background in order to delete the cookie.

Code for that JQ callback action:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var alert = $('#Cmessage'); 

$(".delete").on('click', function(){

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.oostpijl.nl/shop/offerte/deletecookie.php',
  type: 'get', // form submit method get/post
  dataType: 'json', // request type html/json/xml
  beforeSend: function() {
    alert.fadeOut();
  },
success: function(result) {
    if(result.error){
        alert.html(result.html).fadeIn();
        console.log(e)
    }else{
        alert.html(result.html).fadeIn();
        }
    }
});
});
});
```

PHP script:

```
<?php
include("_offertesettings.php");
if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) ){   
    setcookie('offerte', '', time() - 3600, '/' , '.oostpijl.nl' );
    setcookie('offerteC', '', time() - 3600, '/', '.oostpijl.nl' );
$result = array("error" => false, "html" => null);
$result["error"] = false;
$result["html"] = "<script type='text/javascript'>setTimeout(function() { window.location='" . $config["BURL"] . "'; }, 10);</script>";
} else {
    $result["error"] = true;
    $result["html"] = "<h3>Error; Neem contact op met de webmaster</h3>";
}
echo json_encode($result);
exit; 
?>
```

Comment: Try a manual delete of the cookie. then create a new one and see if you still get the same error.

Comment: you're not reading my question right. I don't get any error code, the php script runs and finished like there is nothing wrong.

Comment: Cookies are managed by browser. PHP manipulates cookies by _requesting the browser_ to act on the HTTP response headers. In your case, does the browser actually read the AJAX call's response header that is meant for cookie manipulation?

Comment: And... how do i find out if it reads it or not?

Comment: And yes somehow i think it does read it cause the cookie is set the same way i want to delete the cookie so that is why i find it is weird it aint getting deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you get inside your isset condition. You should test it by printing something as a test then exit.

```
if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) ){
 echo json_encode('test');
 exit;
}
```

also make sure there is no error in your included file "_offertesettings.php". You can check if there are PHP errors by adding those lines at the top of your PHP script.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

to delete your cookies you just need this:

```
setcookie('offerte', '', time() - 3600);
setcookie('offerteC', '', time() - 3600);
```

Comment: Yes the IF statement is MET, so the script runs the setcookie but it doesn't get accepted by the browser, while the directory is the same from where the cookie is set, also its set to / so that should not make a difference. And the domain is set to .domein.tld so that should also not make a difference.

Comment: I also said i can create a cookie the same way i want to delete one so your answer doesn't make any sense to me...

Comment: To delete a cookie it's to put its value to NULL and put its expiration date to a past date. That's what is being done with setcookie('offerte', '', time() - 3600)
If the cookie doesn't get delete then that means its name is not right, or your script is interrupted by something else.

Comment: Even if I would set it not null it should change the content of the cookie and that's not the case. Also the name is correct.

Comment: AND I ALSO SAID that the script is not interrupted since it passes me my js to refresh the page

Comment: ok, try reading the cookie then like that:
echo json_encode('The cookie is set to ' . $_COOKIE['offerte']);
exit;

If your cookie is already properly set then you should be able to get its value sent back to your javascript code.

Comment: It is also properly set. A other php script can read it and load all the 665 characters that it has. That file is: _offertesettings.pho that is in the same folder. Also I used serialize and unserialize. Stil need to change that to json since it is about 20% faster. I'm really dissapointed in the feedback I get here. I think it has something to do with what ejay said. JavaScript does the GET REQUEST on the background of the page when I click a button. Then it returns the value true or false allong with a error message that I defined or it sends me the js. So maybe something with XML ?